# "Submit Query" shows instead of buttons in Crystal Reports and ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

Why does my crystal report viewer only shows the word "Submit Query" instead of the image for its buttons when I deploy my ASP.NET project on IIS 6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely happening because the images used for the buttons can't be found at the path they're supposed to be.

Some google-fu turned up this:

Copy the contents of

```
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\ASP.NETClientFiles\CrystalReportWebFormViewer4
```

To

```
C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet_client\system_web\2_0_50727\CrystalReportWebFormViewer4
```

More info on the Crystal Reports virtual directory:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms225591.aspx